# overflow y property

Tags: css

I have used the `overflow-y: auto;` property to set scroll for overflown values of a column. However the overflow also gets applied to the x-axis, but I don't want that. Is there an alternative, or any changes I need to make so that it only overflows on the y-axis?

```
.leftbarInner {
    width: 150px;
    *width: 135px;
    height: 448px;
    *height: 442px;
    background-color: #5C7E9F;
    padding-right: 5px;
    *padding-right: 0px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I am using IE 7 as a browser.

Comment: overflow-y, overflow-x do not run in every browser. Please show us your code and edit your question. Be a little bit more specific.

Comment: I've improved the formatting of the question, but I'm not sure what the stars prefixing some of your properties are.

Comment: this class is for mine project left side submnenus where if menu reach max height then i need scroll for that thats why i used overflow-y:auto and on each selected menu i have white background color which pass through column and indicates this is selected one but after applying overflow-y that property getting hidden

Answer (score 1):

You can find some nice examples of overflow x and y here: http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

Note that it does not display same in all browsers and is a css3 property.

Answer (score 0):

Check you don't have overflow:auto; after below two css properties.  CSS properties also gets applied in the order you specify them.  So if overflow:auto is after overflow-x:hidden; then it will override and still show x-axis scroll.

```
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
```